# how to format data acquired using powershell import-csv

Tags: excel, csv, powershell

I imported a csv file using import-csv. I only wanted the account number from the list.
 [image: data from import-csv]

I used

```
$Numbers = Import-Csv csv.csv |Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Account Number' |Where-Object {$_ -ne "0"} | Out-Null
```

but i want enclose the account number with "'" and separate the account number with ",". Ideally the list should look like: 'account1','account2',...,'accountlast'. I could not manipulate the $ number variable like array.

Comment: `$numbers = ''; ipcsv csv.csv | select -exp 'Account Number' | ? {$_ -ne '0'} | % {$numbers += "'$_',"}; $numbers = $numbers.trim(','); $numbers`

Comment: @AnthonyStringer worked well thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some string manipulation and a `-join` should be able to get this for you. Although an array which is returned from `Import-Csv csv.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Account Number' | Where-Object {$_ -ne "0"}` would be considered more versatile!

```
$numbers = "'{0}'" -f ((Import-Csv csv.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Account Number' | Where-Object {$_ -ne "0"}) -join "','")
```

Join the account numbers with `','` and then we use the format operator to enclose that into the outer single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close.  You can import the csv, select the object, then use a foreach to format each object, and finally write to the host with one line instead of breaks for each.

```
Import-Csv csv.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Account Number' | Where-Object {$_ -ne "0"} | ForEach{"'" + $_ + "', "} | Write-Host -NoNewLine
```

Comment: the value returned for the code is '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '', the account number is not added

Comment: My apologies, dont need the second account number.  Changed code above.

Comment: there is a comma after the last account number